# To determine of box is a partof diagonal of matrix

Tags: java, math, matrix, computer-science, diagonal

I am trying to figure out how I can do this :
Determine where the given box belongs which row, which column and which diagonal
The matrix would be n x n always of any size.

for eg :

```
0,0 | 1,0 | 2,0
0,1 | 1,1 | 2,1
0,2 | 1,2 | 2,2
```

Now this is the sample 2x2 matrix with the coordinates. 
If the given box was 0,2. 
I can figure out easily its from 0th column lies in 2nd row. but how can I tell that its part of second diagonal ->
I have 
first diagonal -> 0,0    1,1    and    2,2
second diagonal -> 2,0   1,1    and    0,2

Please let me know if theirs a formula or easier way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: For an entry (r,c) of a matrix, you can say: When `r==c` then the entry is on the diagonal, and when `r==(size-1-c)` then the entry is on the other diagonal.

Comment: Also note that if n is an odd number then it is possible that the requested element belongs to both diagonals.. When r == c && r == n/2+1

Comment: Correction about both diagonals for odd n>1: when r==c && r== n/2

Answer (score 0):

Let `A` be your matrix and `A(i,j)` the element in the i-th row, j-th column, where the indices run from `0` to `N-1`. You have defined `A(i,j)=(i,j)`. So, given an element `(i,j)`, you trivially know that it belongs to the `i`-th row and `j`-th column. Also, the diagonals satisfy the equations `i-j=0` and `i+j=N-1`, respectively. So, given `(i,j)`, to test which diagonal it lies on, if any, check if it satisfies either of these equations.